# Finding probability density function for $Z$ which is a function of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $(X,Y)$ be uniform  on the unit square. Let $Z=\frac{X}{Y}$. Find the density of $Z$.

I found typically when they said $(X,Y)$ has a uniform distribution on the unit square it is defined as

$f(x,y) =  \begin{cases}  
1, & \text{ if } 0\leq x \leq 1\\
0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
$

I tried to solve the main problem like this:

First find cdf and from there I calculate the pfd function.

$F_Z(z) = P(Z\leq z)= p(g(x,y) \leq z) = \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{X}{Y}dxdy$

Probably I should change this to be a function of z which I don't know how. Since I don't know I just continue integrating with respect to x and y I will have
$= \int_0^1\frac{1}{2y}dy = \frac{1}{2}\ln (1) -\ln(0)$ which is not defined

Apparently something is not right here, Can anyone help please?

Comment: Got something from an answer below?

Answer (score 3):

Seeing the number of similar questions on the site, let us try to delineate some clear and automatic methods.

---

**First step: Write correctly the joint PDF.** Here, the PDF $f$ of $(X,Y)$ is defined *on the whole plane $\mathbb R^2$* (as every other joint PDF) by the formula $$f(x,y)=\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<y<1}$$
Again:

> *First motto:* The joint PDF of any $d$-dimensional random vector should be defined on the whole space $\mathbb R^d$, not only on a subset of $\mathbb R^d$.

**Second step: Deduce the joint PDF of a transformed couple.** Here, one can consider $(Z,T)=(X/Y,Y)$ (but other choices for the second coordinate $T$ are possible).

Then $(X,Y)=(ZT,T)$ hence $dxdy=tdzdt$ and the [change of variable formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Multiple_variables) based on the Jacobian of the transformation $(x,y)\to(z,t)=(x/y,y)$ yields the joint PDF $g$ of $(Z,T)$ as $$g(z,t)=|t|\,f(x,y)=|t|\,f(zt,t)=t\,\mathbf 1_{0<zt<1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<t<1}$$

> *Second motto:* Get yourself familiar with the change of variables formula.

**Third step: Marginalize the joint PDF to deduce the desired PDF.** Here, the PDF $f_Z$ of $Z$ is simply $$f_Z(z)=\int_\mathbb Rg(z,t)dzdt=\int_0^1t\,\mathbf 1_{0<t<1/z}dt=\mathbf 1_{z>0}\int_0^{\min\{1,1/z\}}tdt=\tfrac12\min\{1,1/z\}^2\mathbf 1_{z>0}$$ An equivalent formulation is $$f_Z(z)=\tfrac12\mathbf 1_{0<z<1}+\tfrac1{2z^2}\mathbf 1_{z>1}$$

> *Third motto:* Well, no real motto for this last step, simply, one can hope you get the automaticity of the approach...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sounds interesting that you derive a procedure, I hope I understand it. A bit higher level of notation which I am not that good in understanding them. In the first step you wrote $f(x,y) = ... $ ,I guess letter L  after equal sign  represents line, is that correct? and I am confused how did you derive g(z,t) in step 2. Sorry if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: @Crimson the letter L you refer to is actually a boldface $1$ and it is known as  the indicator function of a set, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: As is written, the PDF $g$ is deduced from the PDF $f$ using the change of variable formula based on the Jacobian of the transformation.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest finding first the distribution function of $Z$:
$$F_Z(a)=P(Z\le a)=P(X\le aY)$$
for $a>0$. This is the area of the part of the square above the line $y=x/a$. Once we have $F_Z$ we can differentiate to get the density
function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't see how I should continue from there, Would you please give more hints or any reference to read if it is possible?

Comment: @Crimson You just draw a picture and compute the area of a polygon...

Comment: It does not need to be a function of $z$?

Comment: @Crimson You can use any letter you like as the variable.

Comment: Sorry for too many questions, I understand what you meant by computing the area of a polygon but I cannot see how I can solve this in terms of function and variable. probably I should read more about this.